# Postgres query for annual sales report by rep. grouped by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to create an annual sales report table by sales rep, showing all the twelve month. The data I have is more or less like in this example:

```
id | rep | date      | price
----------------------------
1    1     2017-01-01  20
2    1     2017-01-20  44
3    2     2017-02-18  13
4    2     2017-03-08  12
5    2     2017-04-01  88
6    2     2017-09-05  67
7    3     2017-01-31  10
8    3     2017-06-01  74
```

The result I need would be like this:

```
Rep Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
----------------------------------------------------
1   64  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   13  12  88  0   0   0   0   67  0   0   0
3   10  0   0   0   0   74  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What would be the most efficient way to write this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use windowed functions with `FILTER`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  "rep",
  COALESCE(SUM(price) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' from "date") = 1) OVER(PARTITION BY "rep"),0) AS Jan,
  COALESCE(SUM(price) FILTER (WHERE extract('month' from "date") = 2) OVER(PARTITION BY "rep"),0) AS Feb
 --....
FROM ta;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/OHLZM30027)**

Warning!

You probably want to partition by `YEAR` too to avoid summing `JAN 2017` and `JAN 2018`.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
select rep,
sum(case when extract('month' from date) = 1 then price else 0 end ) as Jan,
sum(case when extract('month' from date) = 2 then price else 0 end ) as Feb 
-- another months here
from t
group by rep
```